# Postgres - query taking long time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which is taking a long time. Is there anyway to write it better and in optimized way:

```
select 1, my_text from (
    select distinct a.my_text||'_'||b.my_text my_text from (
        select r_id, my_text 
        from tmp_v 
        where r_id in (
            select o_id 
            from tmp_recid
        ) and v_id in (
            select v_id 
            from o_v 
            where v_id in (
                select o_id from tmp_record_vaid 
                union 
                select o_id from tmp_vue_vaid
            ) and va_nm = 'My V'
        )
    ) a,
    (
        select r_id, my_text 
        from tmp_v 
        where r_id in (
            select o_id 
            from tmp_recid
        ) and v_id in (
            select v_id 
            from o_v 
            where v_id in (
                select o_id from tmp_record_vaid 
                union 
                select o_id from tmp_vue_vaid
            ) and va_nm = 'My V 2'
        )
    ) b
where a.r_id = b.r_id
except 
    select e_nm 
    from myp_ent_id 
    where p_m_id = 1 and entity_id in (
        select entity_id 
        from o_e_t 
        where p_m_id = 1 and tag = 'Ample' and tag_category = 'My Type'
    )
) a;
```

Comment: yikes, so many inner queries. try to avoid them, e.g. by rewriting into joins. And for an analysis beyond that the indices you have are important. Take a look at what the query explanation says -> check the EXPLAIN keyword.

Comment: These are actually harmless subqueries, except that the first two needlessly select from the same table twice. For an answer, you have to provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the query.

Comment: Do I smell an EAV-model here?

Comment: @joop - you got it :)

Comment: What's a value and relationship of "e_nm" from " select e_nm 
    from myp_ent_id"?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic the query is implementing.

Answer (score 0):

First level optimization: I combined two sub queries a and b(tmp_v) into one using CASE as the conditions are common for both.

```
select 1,my_text(
select distinct string_agg(amytext,'')||'_'||string_agg(bmytext,'') as mytext(
select r_id,case va_nm='My V' then my_text else null end as amy_text,case va_nm='My V 2' then my_text else null end as bmy_text
from tmp_v 
where r_id in 
(select o_id from tmp_recid) 
and v_id in (select v_id from o_v where v_id in (select o_id from tmp_record_vaid union select o_id from tmp_vue_vaid))
)
except 
select e_nm 
from myp_ent_id 
where p_m_id = 1 and entity_id in (
        select entity_id 
        from o_e_t 
        where p_m_id = 1 and tag = 'Ample' and tag_category = 'My Type'
)
)a;
```

Further you can replace IN with EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

please, try with below query except "except query":

```
select 1, distinct(CONCAT(TV1.my_text, '_'))
from tmp_v TV1
left outer join tmp_recid TR1 on TR1.o_id = TV1.r_id
left outer join o_v OV1 on OV1.v_id = TV1.v_id and OV1.va_nm in ('My V', 'My V 2')

left outer join tmp_record_vaid TRV1 on OV1.v_id = TRV1.o_id
left outer join tmp_vue_vaid TVV1 on OV1.v_id = TVV1.o_id

where TR1.o_id is not null and (TRV1.o_id is not null OR TVV1.o_id is not null)
group by TV1.r_id
```

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. You have to put it right after the SELECT and it always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing a single column or expression with parentheses won't change the behaviour of DISTINCT. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`